Example of a theory in the signature of a single binary operation which is the same as the theory of its finite models.
Consider the signature $\{*\}$, that is, the signature consisting of just a single binary operation. Does there exist a theory $T$ in that signature, where $T$ has both finite and infinite models, such that the first-order theory of the class of its finite models is the same as $T$ itself? If not in that signature, is there at least some other finite signature where there is such a theory $T$?

The theory of all finite structures with a single binary operation would work, no? It has infinite models per compactness theorem.

(The same goes for any signature.)

@DavidGao Yes, but I am looking for an explicitly given axiomatization of a theory.

I would assume this theory is axiomatizable by an axiom schema saying given any $n$-tuple of terms (possibly with parameters) that has $n$ inputs, if it defines an injective function, then the function it defines must also be surjective (and perhaps vice versa). But that’s just my guess. I have no idea how to prove it.

Not for the signature you proposed, but say, for the empty signature ${}$, the theory $T$ of all finite models is axiomatized by the empty set ${}$, so that would be an example.

just let $T$ say that the image of $\ast$ is a single element – then this theory is bi-interpretable with the empty theory in the language consisting of a single constant symbol, and it is complete (indeed categorical in every cardinality) after adding an axiom saying there are $n$ elements for fixed $n\in\omega$ or adding the axiom scheme saying there are infinitely many elements

(so $T$ is just $\forall x\forall y\forall u\forall v(xy=uv)$)

I was referring to "The theory of all finite structures with a single binary operation would work, no?" I missed the word "finite" there. My bad!

@NoahSchweber I see. No worries. By the way, are you aware whether the axiomatization I proposed actually works? It’s in my third comment. Specifically, I proposed that the theory of all finite ${\ast}$-structures is axiomatized by an axiom schema as follows: for any $n$-tuple of terms $(t_1, \cdots, t_n)$ in $n+m$ variables $x_1, \cdots, x_n, y_1, \cdots, y_m$, we have an axiom saying for any $y_1, \cdots, y_m$, the function $(x_1, \cdots, x_n) \mapsto (t_1(x_1, \cdots, x_n, y_1, \cdots, y_m), \cdots, t_n(x_1, \cdots, x_n, y_1, \cdots, y_m))$ is injective iff it is surjective.

I was thinking of asking a question about this, but I just want to check if there’s an obvious reason why this wouldn’t work or if this is already well-known to be true or not true.

@DavidGao I suspect you may need to go broader than just terms, and use a scheme ranging over definable functions, but I'm not certain.

@NoahSchweber Thanks! That's an interesting idea. But isn't definability depending on the theory? This seems like it might end up being circular. If, instead, we're just considering definability relative to the empty theory, if there are only function symbols in the language, it feels like we shouldn't have any definable functions except terms. (Again, just a guess.)

@NoahSchweber In any case, I think I'm assured that this isn't just completely obvious, so I'll move this to a new question instead of considering this in the comments here.

@DavidGao I was being a bit loose - I should have said over formulas which might define functions. Note that even in the empty theory there are formulas which define functions in all structures but aren't provably equivalent to any term, e.g. $f(x,y)=x$ if there are at most 17 elements and $y$ otherwise.

@NoahSchweber Ah, I see what you meant. I thought this could only happen if there are both constant symbols and function symbols with parity at least $1$, but I suppose I was mistaken. Thanks! I'll mention this in the question I just posted.

@AtticusStonestrom Very belatedly, you should turn that into an answer.
